# Backbone.js defaults are ignored if attributes are passed on initialization

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I bumped into very unpleasant situation.

Here is code for model's initialization:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    var attrs = attributes || {};
    options || (options = {});
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
    this.attributes = {};
    if (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
    if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
    attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, _.result(this, 'defaults'));
    this.set(attrs, options);
    this.changed = {};
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

The problem here is that when model gets attributes map on init it ignores default values if attribute is already existing and will not set default value prior to setting what was passed to constructor.

Logically thinking I would expect that defaults are always set at the very beginning of initialization and then values would be replaced when "set" method is called that way I could override "set" method to handle array type attributes and convert them to collection like so:

```
set: function () {
    var firstArgument = arguments[0],
        attributesMap;
    if (_.isObject(firstArgument)) {
        //setting with attributes map
        attributesMap = firstArgument;
        _.each(attributesMap, function (value, attribute) {
            var modelAttribute = this.attributes[attribute];
            if (modelAttribute && modelAttribute instanceof Backbone.Collection) {
                modelAttribute.reset(value);
                delete attributesMap[attribute];
            }
        }, this);
    }

    return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Now what I'm doing - is checking if default attribute is instance of Backbone.Collection and if so I reset collection with given array values (keeping the same collection reference and allowing views or other data objects to listen to that collection) and prevent it from being overwritten with regular array.

Because of the problem I described earlier when calling "set" method it does not have default attributes and I can not check what's the type of attribute that I want to manipulate.

How do you deal with attributes that are arrays and that should be converted and treated as Backbone.Collection?

For now I just changed what "defaults" function do and instead of returning attributes object I do this:

```
defaults: function () {
    this.attributes = {
        ...
    };
}
```

Comment: See if I understand this correct. Normally when you pass attributes on initialisation they override the defaults, but you want the defaults to stay in tact?

Comment: No I want defaults to be set on initialization just before "set" method is called so when I override "set" method I can check what is attribute's type. And defaults would be overwritten when "set" method was called. Now the flow is: 1) Create model 2) Check if passed attributes contain all values that are defined with "defaults" and merge what's missing 3) Call set method
I would prefer this: 1) Create model 2) Set default values 3) Call set method and override those values with whatever you have.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do and why, sorry.

Comment: I have a nested model which has few attributes that are array and I want to convert them to collection when "set" method is called

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from Backbone sources

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    var attrs = attributes || {};
    options || (options = {});
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
    this.attributes = {};
    if (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
    if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
    attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, _.result(this, 'defaults'));    // (1)
    this.set(attrs, options);    
    this.changed = {};
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

As you can see on (1), it use underscore default, which simply merge the objects overriding, before calling set.

I guess a solution to your problem could be to call set twice, like this:

```
    ...
    if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};

    this.set( _.result(this, 'defaults') , options);   // set the default attrs
    this.changed = {};
    this.set( _.defaults({}, attrs) , options);        // set the attrs as passed in arguments
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

It will of course be cleaner to define a new model and leave backbone source untouched.

Also although I may guess what you want to do, I think you should consider another way to to it.

I hope that help!